# How to create keyboard shortcut for an extension's function in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-code

I managed to install [ftp-sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukasz-wronski.ftp-sync) by Łukasz Wroński and I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut for the command "Ftp-sync: Sync current file to Remote".

Whatever I try, I get the following warning "Command 'Ftp-sync: Sync current file to Remote' not found".

So how can I create a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had to look in the "extension.js" file of the extension for the command (extension.ftpsyncsingle). After finding the appropriate command, I used it in creating the keyboard shortcut in File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.